# How to use v-if to to return true if route ends in number

Tags: vue.js

How do I replace `*` so that this v-if only matches a route ending in a number.

```
<div v-if="route().current('reporter.*')">
```

It should be true for `/reporter/18` and be false for `/reporter/home`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regex match:

```
<div v-if="$router.currentRoute.path.match(/reporter\/\d+/)">
```

(depending on how you get the current route as a string)

Answer (score 0):

There’s a javascript function [isNaN](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)